# Finding vertex of $xy^2=1$ .

Tags: conic-sections

> $$ xy^2 = 1$$

From the equation,  it can be said that it is a rectangular hyperbola . Now if I want to calculate the vertex of it , I do follows :

$$\rightarrow (\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2})^2 - (\frac{x}{2} - \frac {y^2}{2})^2=1$$
$$\rightarrow X^2-Y^2=1$$

where,  $X=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}$ and $Y=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}$ .

Now,  for vertex :
$$X=\pm a,Y=0 (a=1)$$
which implies :
$$ \frac{x}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}=\pm 1 ....(i) $$
$$ \frac{x}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}=0 ....(ii) $$

Working with $(i)$  and $(ii)$  , I get :
$x=\pm 2, y=0$ .

This,  vertex is  **$(\pm 2,0)$** .
**Am I correct ?**

Comment: $xy^2=1$ is not a rectangular hyperbola, or any conic section. The equation of a conic has degree $2$, but $xy^2=1$ has degree $3$. Moreover, $(\pm 2, 0)$ cannot be a vertex, since it does not satisfy the equation: $(\pm 2)(0)^2 = 0 \neq 1$.

Comment: But the graph seems to be a hyperbola... Or is it only a curve like other 3-degree polynomials? @Blue

Comment: Lots of graphs *seem* to be hyperbolas. :)  This one, however, isn't terribly convincing: Its "branches" live in the first and fourth quadrants; a hyperbola's branches would be in opposite quadrants (say, first and third, or second and fourth). What you have is a cubic curve. [These have been classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve), but the classification is far more elaborate than ellipse/parabola/hyperbola.